# Evaluating Cauchy principal value

Tags: complex-analysis

During a graduate course on Electrodynamics I began reviewing the Kramer-Kronig relations, which are defined using the Cauchy principal value. However, I have some trouble understanding how to evaluate the Cauchy principal value, since it's a topic of complex analysis I never saw before and so far the articles and books I've read just offer the formal definition without examples.

First of all, I understand that if $h(z)$ is singular in $z=0$, then the principal value can be evaluated as [1],

$$P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} h(z)dz=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0^+}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{-a} h(z)dz+\int_a^{+\infty} h(z)dz\right]$$

However, this only applies if $h(z)$ has one pole in $z=0$. If, for example, I have the function,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\omega}{z(z-z_0)}dz$$

How is the principal value defined in this case?

I have also found in other documents that the definition of the principal value is a bit different, as for example, in [2] they define the principal value as,

$$P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(z)dz=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{+R}h(z)dz$$

which can be evaluated as usual using the residue theorem, so I'm confused why there're are two definitions, one of which is actually familiar.

[1] https://math.tutorvista.com/calculus/cauchy-principal-value.html

[2] http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/312Fall13/Handouts/lecture34_dec_2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are referred to as the "Principal Value", and give the practical result we would expect from contour integration. Both forms can be seen as a specialization of
$$P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty f = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \left[\int_{b-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}^{b-\varepsilon} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{b+\varepsilon}^{b+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right]$$

whenever $f$ has a singularity at $b,$ but even then we need  a more general definition when $f$ has more singularities. A better definition is to simply define the Principal Value by 
$$P.V.\int_{C} f(z) \ \mathrm{d}z = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{C \setminus \mathcal{N}_\epsilon (b)} f(z)\ \mathrm{d}z$$ where $C$ is a contour in the complex plane and $\mathcal{N}_\epsilon (b)$ is ball of radius $\epsilon$ about a singularity $b$ of $f.$ Since complex singularities are isolated, we can obviously break up our integral and handle each singularity separately, so this is fully general.

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, then for every singularity in $f(z)$ then we can break the integral as it passes around it in the limit when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$. Regarding the notation, what does $C \setminus \mathcal{N}_\epsilon (b)$ stand for?

Comment: @Charlie It is the contour $C$ minus the neighborhood (ball of radius $\epsilon$) about the point $b.$ You can think of it as a curve with a piece cut out around the singularity

Comment: Thank you. Now that I see it, it's very similar to the definition of the Feynman propagator in QFT, just with a different notation.